# mongoose, post data using form-data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I wan,t to post data from web form to database
and this is all of my code

**script.js**

```
$scope.save1 =function()
{
    var input2 = {
        "_id":$scope.iduser,
        "Name":$scope.username,
        "position":$scope.position,
        "level":$scope.level,
        "acclevel":$scope.data.acclevel,
        "status":$scope.status1,
        "pass":$scope.pass
    }
    $http.post("http://localhost:22345/user",input2)
    .success(function(res) {
        if(res.error == 0)
        {
            $scope.status1 = "active";
            $scope.iduser = "";
            $scope.username = "";
            $scope.position = "";
            $scope.level = "";
            $scope.data.acclevel = "";
            $scope.pass = "";
            $scope.IdUser = false;
            alert("save success");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(res.User);
        }
    });
}   }]);
```

**my rest API (user.js)**

```
app.post("/user",function(req,res){

    var users = new user(req.body);
    users.save(function(err,users){
        if(err)
        {
            data['error'] = 1;
            data['User'] = err;
            res.json(data);
        }
        else
        {
            data['error'] = 0;
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
});
```

**models**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
_id : String,
Name : String,
position : String,
level : String,
status : String,
pass : String},{ collection: 'user'});
var user = mongoose.model("user",user);
module.exports.user = user;
```

when i try to post using postman using form-data, i always get an error result but if i use x-www-form-urlencoded, i can get success result, so whats the problem from mya code. thank you

**update**

finaly I found the problem, it's happend when I try to crate header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,etc) co I change it with this

```
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");     
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With,X-HTTP-Methods-Override,Content-Type,Accept,Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin,Authorization, Content-Type");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method){
    return res.send(200);
}
next();
});
```

so thanks for all answers

Comment: can you share the error message?

Comment: I mean I always get result from rest API 'if(err)' when i use form-data in postman

Comment: To handle `multipart/form-data` in Express, you need a module like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). The regular `body-parser` middleware doesn't handle it.

Comment: @danilodeveloper after i check, it' look like i got error status 200, and the input that use from script.js (when i use it for angularjs) is undefined from the console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` are different type of `form content type` defined by `W3C`.

`x-www-form-urlencoded` is `Default`, it is used to send `simple text/ASCII` data.

`Form-data` is used when you have `non-ASCII data` or `large Binary data`.

**According to the w3.org documentation:**

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.

In your case, you have `simple text/ASCII data`. Thus, `x-www-form-urlencoded` will work instead of `form-data`.

Read [Documentation on Form Content Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) by w3.org for better understanding of these form content types.

you can also refer to [Postman Docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) to clear your doubts.

I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: so what should I do to make it work in form-data too? because I use it for input data from html angularjs form

Comment: why do you need to send it using `form-data`? it is basically used when you are uploading a file or something. See the documentation i shared with you.